# What is Systick in embedded systems and what are they used for?

Tags: embedded, system, interrupt, cycle

Im studying a course in embedded systems and going over interrupts. I have come across Systick and cycle times. What are they, when and why are they used?

Comment: You could ask the question really easy to google

Comment: Short answer: It's just a timer interrupt. Often set at 1KHz so it becomes a millisecond-counter-interrupt.

Answer (score 3):

Systick is simply a timer present inside ARM based microcontrollers. Basic purpose is to provide help generate accurate interrupts to different tasks (of RTOS).

It has multiple uses aside from that. For example, many developers use it to generate an accurate delay function. Other benefits are portability where you can easily take an RTOS task from one microcontroler to a different one, and not end up changing the scheduling time and time dependent interrupts for tasks, as there can be different clock sources being used on the new microcontroler.

If you wanna know more about it, refer to ARM's online documentation.
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/ar01s02s08.html
If you don't know what is RTOS, read the following article for a quick overview.
https://www.freertos.org/about-RTOS.html